# Why aren't my saved passwords showing up?

Tags: google-chrome

In the 'Saved passwords' area in the settings for Chrome, all I see is

'Your saved passwords will appear here. Learn more'

Despite the fact I know there are saved passwords in there and can go to a site that loads my passwords fine.

What gives?[image]

Here's what I see:

Even though I clearly have saved passwords:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't show your passwords in plain text if that's what you're asking?  Mine are showing up find under the 'Manage saved passwords' section so that means the functionality is working.

Try the IT-101 options.  Uninstall/Reboot/Reinstall.  Clear cache.  Upgrade. etc.

Also - I can't actually find a 'Saved Passwords' section in Chrome.  Can you be more specific around how you've gotten to that section?

Comment: As I said, it just says the default 'Your saved passwords will appear here' message, as if you have no saved passwords.

Comment: Yes re-install did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

My Gnome Keyring locked up (The gui is known as Passwords and Keys / Seahorse). All I had to do was unlock my login keystore and chrome was able to pick them up after. The situation seems to also happen on macs, but with Keychain instead.

[image]